# Include only a particular definition from header file

Tags: c, header, string.h

I have used strlen() function from the string.h library without including the header which I want to include from the header file which is initially implemented, because I am writing my own implementation of strcpy(),if I include the header it says it's multiple definitions of strcpy ().
So how do I include only a particular definition from the header file.
Do I need to use extern keyword?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "exercise 5.5.h"

int main() {
  char *s = "hello";
  char *t = "helli";
  int n = 3;
  if (n > strlen(t))
    printf("\nsorry the value of n is greater than the size of t");
  else {
    S = strncpy(s, t, n);
    printf("\nther is %d", x);
  }
}
```

The header has definition of strncpy

Terminal trace

```
exercise. 5.5_main.c:10:7: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function "strien
exercise 5.5 main.c:10:7: note: include <string.h> or provide a declaration of 'strlen
```

I don't want to include string.h but how do I explicitly provide definition of strlen

Header

```
char* strncat(char *s, char *t, int n);
char* strncpy(char *s, char *t, int n);
int strncmp(char *s,char *t, int n);
```

Comment: You can't according to C standard, it a reserved name. You can disallow the standard library and only use yours function. You can also create a library that include your implementation and preload it to force a program to use it. Without [mcve] it's hard to exactly know what you try and what you need. Currently, I will tell you that this problem has nothing to do with header.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I guess you try to do an exercise, can you include it in your question ? Because as I said, you are not allowed to define your own `strlen()` function in the C standard. I doubt that your exercice ask you that. For exemple, are you sure that your exemple tell you to name your function `strlen()` and not for exemple `my_strlen()` ?

Comment: As a plus, to post a complete [mcve], you need to provide the header file "exercise 5.5.h" in your question.

Comment: What if I need the same name

Comment: You do not need the same name. Either you do not because your assignment doesn't require it. Or you do not need to use a different prototype for the function you want to overwrite, in that case you can simply rewrite the strcpy nder the same name and prototype. If you do not want to use the same prototype, then you do not want to use the same name either. Otherwise how do you want to make all those other users of the function use the new prototype for the same name?

Comment: Writing your own functions with identical names to standard library functions is very bad practice.  You can, but it is a support nightmare.  C does not stop you being a bad programmer if you really want to, but why would you want to?

Comment: It says that you must provide declaration of strlen(). Open manual and copy it into your program.

Comment: Do you know what is big buffer?

Comment: `strien` (note the `i`) in `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function "strien` is not in the posted code.

Comment: @chux Perhaps the OP laboriously retyped those messages, instead of copying and pasting them verbatim as you or I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reimplementing a standard library function like `strcpy` can be tricky.  Since it's a standard library function, its name is in a sense "reserved" -- you're not supposed to use it yourself.  (It's not quite as strongly reserved as is a keyword like `switch`, but it's still generally a bad idea to try to write a function named `strcpy` -- not to mention the fact that it's usually perfectly unnecessary!)

In answer to your explicit question, no, there's no way to "selectively include" just your own selection of the declarations in a system header file such as `<string.h>`.

If for some reason you need to write your own version of `strcpy`, you have several choices, depending on circumstances.

1. Rename your own function.  For example, call it `my_strcpy`.  (This is the usual approach.)
2. Make sure the definition of your function is perfectly correct, and matches the declaration in the standard header file exactly.  For example, if you have `strcpy(char *dst, char *src) {...}` or `char *strcpy(char *dst, char *src) {...}`, those are both wrong -- it needs to be `char *strcpy(char *dst, const char *src) {...}`.
3. Don't use the standard `strlen` function, either, meaning that you don't have to do a `#include <string.h>` at all.  If you need it, write your own version of `strlen`, too.  (This is often the requirement if the reason you're writing your own `strcpy` is as a teaching exercise: often the assignment says "You may not use any other functions from the standard library.")
4. Instead of doing a `#include <string.h>` because you're calling `strlen`, provide your own prototype for it at the top of your file: `extern size_t strlen(const char *);`.  (This is generally an extremely bad idea for several reasons, and is not a step to be taken except under extreme circumstances and when you know exactly what you're doing.)

It may also be significant to note whether the "redefinition" error you're getting is coming from the compiler or the linker.  If it's a compile-time error such as "`conflicting types for 'strcpy'`", it indicates you probably need to pay attention to point 2 just above.  But if it's a link-time error like "`ld: duplicate symbol '_strcpy'`" there may not be anything you can do about it, and you'll have to fall back on point 1.